# On Cascade Delete does not seem to be applying in my DB

Tags: mysql, sql

I don't know what I am doing wrong as I've been looking at previous answers on this site concerning `ON CASCADE DELETE`.

Basically this is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE `directorycolumntags` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `directorycolumn_id` INT(11)  NOT NULL,
  `tag_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `description` TEXT,
  `created` DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`directorycolumn_id`) REFERENCES directorycolumn(id),
  CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (`tag_id`) REFERENCES tag(id) 
  ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=MYISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=29 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The `Foreign key` references the `id` of the tag table:

```
CREATE TABLE `tag` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` TEXT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT=29 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Now, If I perform this `query` to `INSERT` some data into the `directorycolumntags` table it works:

INSERT INTO directorycolumntags (directorycolumn_id, tag_id) VALUES (178,32);

However, when I `DELETE` the entry from the tag table with the `id` of 32 it does not remove the row from the directorycolumntags table. Can anyone point out where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

It's because your table `directorycolumntags` is `MYISAM`, not `INNODB`. MyISAM doesn't support foreign keys. You can write your foreign key statements, but MySQL silently ignores them.

Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE `directorycolumntags` ENGINE = 'InnoDB';
```